# Adding Item to Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, combobox

I have a `Silverlight` application with a `ComboBox` that is filled by `VideoCaptureDevice`'s.

```
cbVideoDevices.ItemsSource = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices();
```

I'm trying to add item, "Select a video device" to the first index but I can't get it to work.

XAML Code:

```
    <ComboBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="cbVideoDevices" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" ItemsSource="{Binding AudioDevices}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAudioDevice}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explicitly setting the `ItemsSource` in the code behind and the XAML, choose one or the other. Ideally you would take the XAML approach and set the `DataContext` appropriately.

Once you make that decision you can insert an item within your `ComboBox` by using the `Items` property.

```
ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
box.Items.Insert(0, "My Item");
```

A better approach would be to leverage the [ICollectionView](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/) and simply sort the data and let the UI respond accordingly. Your `ItemsSource` would then be bound to the `ICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily insert an item at a desired index location in the Items collection of the ComboBox using the following code.

```
         TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
        t.Text = "Select a video device"
        combo.Items.Insert(0, t);
```

Setting the selected index will set the ComboBox to show your added item by default:

```
   combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or

you can do like this..

```
   YourClassObject objSelectItem = new YourClassObject(); 
    objSelectItem.ID = "0"; 
    objSelectItem.Name = "Select Item"; 
    ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0,objSelectItem);
```

i hope it will helps you...